# Kernels from unplugged external hard drive showing in GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have an external hard drive loaded with Ubuntu 16.10 on it, and I recently plugged it in then unplugged it to find that the next time I booted my laptop, the kernels from the Ubuntu installation on my external hard drive showed up in the GRUB menu. GRUB looks very cluttered because of this, and I'd like to be able to remove them from the menu. How would I go about doing this, either through the command line or otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

Grub doesn't detect all the kernels it references on every startup; they're stored in a list that it reads when it starts.  As long as the list isn't updated, Grub will display the same kernel options.  You can run `sudo update-grub` with the external drive unplugged and it will remove the entries that are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Grub will only update its list of bootable filesystems when it is told to, either manually by you by using `sudo update-grub` or when, for instance, you upgrade a kernel using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` or the updater.

Another option if you prefer the graphical approach is to install Grub Customizer. It's not available in the official repositories but it allows you to setup Grub from a GUI if you wanted to, for instance, change the default OS loaded when you boot your PC. This will update the list of OS's when you open it, but will not write the changes to disk until you ask it to. If this would interest you I can post the link to the ppa but be advised this wouldn't be from an official Ubuntu source.

Use caution when doing anything with Grub though. It's small, but it's responsible for you being able to boot your system. I'd recommend against manually trying to delete entries, always accept the list that `sudo update`grub` or the Grub Customizer provides. The only things I'd ever change are the menu timeouts and the default entry. If your list is too long and you want to remove entries you should post a different question asking how to safely remove old kernels, but this isn't usually a concern as old kernels are all contained within their own sub menu on the loading screen so you'll only see one entry for Linux and one entry for Advanced Options along with the memtest entries and your other installed OS's